# Getting error On data Fetch

Tags: php, codeigniter

I fetched data and fill the value inside the table with for each loop like:

```
<?php
foreach ($data['rows'] as $value) {
?>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $value->rsdntname; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $value->rsdntemail;?></td>
<td> <?php echo $value->rsdntphone; ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

but in top section i have three columns which also filled with the fetch data like:

```
<h3 class="form-section">Building
 <span class="pull-right" style="font-size:15px;color:#000;">
 Core <?php $data['rows']->aptcore; ?>,
Floor,
Apartment No
 </span>
 </h3>
```

But it is returning me this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: admin/page.php
Line Number: 52
```

Why I am getting this error .. Provide me the solution Not able to understand.and give me the solution i am not able to understand .It saying tryng to access non object y this error returning with that. what i am doing wrong there 
working with same page to access data for another level with loop its working outside the loop its not working

Comment: this sounds stranger Core <?php $data['rows']->aptcore; ?, if is a array of typos. Not got anyone at firslevel, only arry of typos

Comment: Please provide the output from `var_dump($data['rows'])`.

Comment: The `foreach` implies to me that `$data['rows']` is an array or collection of some kind.  I wouldn't expect it to have a property called `aptcore`.  What actually are these variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to read a property from an object:

```
$data['rows']->aptcore;
```

But the error is telling you that it's not an object.  So what is it?  This previous line of code implies to me that it's probably an array:

```
foreach ($data['rows'] as $value) {
```

Because you're looping over the array and reading properties from *each* object therein.

In a comment elsewhere on this page you specify some debugging output (`print_r($data);`):

```
Array (
  [res] => 1
  [rows] => Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
      [buldname] => BT Tower
      [aptno] => 901
      [aptcore] => 2
      [aptfloor] => 2
      [rsdntname] => Gaurav
      [rsdntemail] => Gaurav@gmail.com
      [rsdntphone] => 9891110987 )
```

(formatting mine)

If I understand that output correctly, `$data` is an associative array with two named elements, `res` and `rows`.  `rows` is itself also an array containing one object.  (Or does it contain more that you're just not showing us?)  An array of one object is still an array, not an object.  (A basket containing one apple is still a basket, not an apple.)

You could try to index the array to access the first element therein:

```
$data['rows'][0]->aptcore
```

Or if there are more elements and you want all of them, you can loop over the array *exactly like you already do*:

```
foreach ($data['rows'] as $value) {
    echo $value->aptcore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `$value` as if it is an object, but more than likely your $value is actually a nested array. Assuming your data in `$data['rows']` are arrays then instead of using `$value->rsdntname` you should call it as `$value['rsdntname']`... and so on for each `$value`.

Comment: @JonStirling fair point, I'm thinking it is normal convention that the array $data['rows'] would also be arrays.

Comment: echo "<pre>";print_r($data);exit;                                                    Array
(
    [res] => 1
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                   [buldname] => BT Tower 
                    [aptno] => 901
                    [aptcore] => 2
                    [aptfloor] => 2
                  
                    [rsdntname] => Gaurav
                    [rsdntemail] => Gaurav@gmail.com
                    [rsdntphone] => 9891110987
                )

Comment: @Arushi trying to replace `$value->rsdntname` with `$value['rsdntname']` does not work then I assume?

Comment: @Arushi: So `$data['rows']` is an array?  When you do `$data['rows']->aptcore` the system has no way of knowing *which* `aptcore` value you want to see.  You're accessing a list of objects which each have that value.  Look at your `foreach` loop, it loops over the array and outputs the values for each one.

Comment: @Arushi can you show us the code that you use that gets `$data` information? the edit button should be available at the bottom left of your question.

Comment: actually from your print_r  value  of aptcore is at $data['rows'][0]->aptcore; so you are missing internal array while accessing.